# Grouping/Subquery in LINQ to Entities with related ungrouped columns

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, group-by

I have this table in DB:

```
ID    | Timestamp           | Score
------|---------------------|-------------------
1     | 2013-01-01 12:00:00 | 15
1     | 2013-01-02 11:00:00 | 1
1     | 2013-01-03 16:00:00 | 4
2     | 2013-01-08 04:00:00 | 7
2     | 2013-01-09 08:00:00 | 9
2     | 2013-01-10 11:00:00 | 6
3     | 2013-01-03 12:00:00 | 14
3     | 2013-01-01 10:00:00 | 15
3     | 2013-01-02 00:00:00 | 17
```

What I need is a last Score for each ID.
In other words, for each ID, I need to pick the row with highest Timestamp and then get the Score from that row.

I managed to do that in SQL server like this (which may not be optimal)

```
SELECT ID, Timestamp, Score FROM Data cd
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT ID as SubId, MAX(Timestamp) AS TS 
     FROM Data GROUP BY ID) AS SUB
ON cd.ID = SUB.SubId
WHERE Timestamp = TS
```

**I need a LINQ to Entities (v4) solution** to this situation, but I am unsure how to approach subqueries and grouping in this situation.

**@Edit** (in reply to comments):
I've tried something like the following, but I don't know how to get the Score from that grouped item, or how to integrate the subquery into this.

```
from d in Datas
group d by d.ID into group
select new { ID = group.Key, TS = group.Max(i => i.Timestamp) }
```

Is this scenario possible? Is there any better solution (performance-wise)?

Comment: What LINQ query did you try?

Comment: I have updated the post with what I've tried. But the whole concept of subquery in LINQ is somewhat blurry for me.

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you are wanting:

```
from d in Datas
group d by d.ID into g
let maxDate = g.Max(d => d.Timestamp) 
select new 
{
    ID = g.Key, 
    Score = g.First(item => item.Timestamp == maxDate).Score
};
```

Here's a copy of the complete code listing that I used in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/):

```
void Main()
{
    var testData = GenerateTestData();

    var result = 
        from d in testData
        group d by d.ID into g
        let maxDate = g.Max(d => d.Timestamp) 
        select new 
        {
            ID = g.Key, 
            Score = g.First(item => item.Timestamp == maxDate).Score
        };

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID={0}; Score={1}", item.ID, item.Score);
    }
}

List<Item> GenerateTestData()
{
    List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
    list.Add(new Item(1, "2013-01-01 12:00:00", 15));
    list.Add(new Item(1, "2013-01-02 11:00:00", 1));
    list.Add(new Item(1, "2013-01-03 16:00:00", 4));
    list.Add(new Item(2, "2013-01-08 04:00:00", 7));
    list.Add(new Item(2, "2013-01-09 08:00:00", 9));
    list.Add(new Item(2, "2013-01-10 11:00:00", 6));
    list.Add(new Item(3, "2013-01-03 12:00:00", 14));
    list.Add(new Item(3, "2013-01-01 10:00:00", 15));
    list.Add(new Item(3, "2013-01-02 00:00:00", 17));
    return list;
}

class Item
{
    public Item(int id, string timestamp, int score)
    {
        ID = id;
        Timestamp = DateTime.Parse(timestamp);
        Score = score;
    }
    public int ID;
    public DateTime Timestamp;
    public int Score;
}
```

Which produced the output:

```
ID=1; Score=4
ID=2; Score=6
ID=3; Score=14
```